# arc4random on Xcode for C

Tags: c, xcode, random, srand, arc4random

I want to do a multiplications quiz using random numbers from 2 variables.
I tried to use this:

```
 int answ

 int rand1= (arc4random()%10)+1;

 int rand2= (arc4random()%20)+1;

 printf("\n¿What is %d * %d?: ", rand1, rand2);

 scanf("%d", &answ);

 if (answ==rand1*rand2)
     printf("\nCorrect answer!");
 else
     printf("\Incorrect answer, the result was %d", rand1*rand2);
```

My problem is that both random numbers does not change when the next question is asked.
I also tried adding srand(time(NULL))  and the same.. (I already have the library stdlib.h added)

What´s missing?

Answer (score 3):

`arc4random()` does not need to be seeded and will return a random number un-related to any previous returned number.

There is a problem with your program such that you are not making new calls to `arc4random()` or the new values are not being used. How are you asking for a new run?

`srand(time(NULL))` is unrelated to `arc4random()`.

Just a heads-up, instead of `arc4random()%10)` you can use `arc4random_uniform(10)`.

Comment: I exchanged arc4random()%10 for arc4random_uniform(10) and still the same. but i resolved it, thanks! I had to ask for a new run as you said!

Comment: Yes, that is not the problem. arc4random works correctly, it is how you are using it, where is the rest of the code that asks more than one question? The supplied code does not even compile, it has two errors.